# gldatepicker on change submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Iam using [gldate picker](http://glad.github.io/glDatePicker/#reference) with my php code so that whenever the textfield change the date will be submitted and then processed in my php file.

Here is my html code:

```
   <html>
     <body>
      <form method="post" action="test.html" name="myfrm" id="frm">

        <input type="text"  id="mydate" /> 

      </form>
   </body>
 </html>
```

And here is my js code:

```
  $(window).load(function()
       {
        $('#mydate').glDatePicker({

            showAlways: true

            });

    onClick: (function(el, cell, date, data) {

        $("#frm").submit();
      })
    });


 </script>
```

Any ideas? I searched this on google but could not find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $(window).load(function()
       {
        $('#mydate').glDatePicker({

            showAlways: true,
             onClick: (function(el, cell, date, data) {

        el.val(date);

        if(data != null) {
          $("#frm").submit();
       }
      });
      });
   });
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply but now have some problem that the form is submitted successfully but its not getting the dates from the calendar. Help will be appreciated thanks.

Comment: I will update you in some minutes right now I am not in front of pc

Comment: its giving i need some reputation to do that :(

Comment: Thanks for the reply sir but its not working its not showing the date in my textfield.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Rituraj probably was correct when he wrote it, but it's not currently working in the latest build. This is what I have:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#mydate').glDatePicker({
        cssName: 'flatwhite',
        hideOnClick: true,
        onClick: (function(el, cell, date, data) {
            if(el.val() != '') {
                $("#frm").submit();
            }
        })
    });
});
```

The `el` parameter relates to the input field that the datepicker is attached to, so this basically states that if the input field isn't empty when you click on a date, fire the submit.